# How can I replace operation print in batch with a message?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I'm working on a simple tool that copies files to and from desired locations and I want to replace the print in the CLI with a message of my choosing, I've looked around and so far all solutions I've found don't implement what I'm looking for. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO D | XCOPY "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Code Snippets" ".\Backup\Code Snippets" /s /q /y
ECHO D | XCOPY "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects" ".\Backup\Projects" /s /q /y
ECHO D | XCOPY "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates" ".\Backup\Templates" /s /q /y
```

I want to make a message display something like *"Backup in progress..."* instead of each operation showing. I have tried combinations of `PRINT`, `ECHO`, and even `CLS` to replace the window contents but I can't get it to work. What am I missing? I have seen other batch scripts do this *(which I no longer have to take notes from)* and would like to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added a redirection of your choosing at the end that isn't on the STDOUT. For example `>nul` or `>file.txt` and corresponding echo statements. You won't be able to show progress during the execution of `xcopy` that way.

```
echo "Copy in progress"
xcopy > nul
echo "Copy finished"
```

Error handling etc. might be more complicated that way.

Answer (score 2):

Use

1. the `@` command prefix to avoid showing a single command;
2. `echo off` to avoid showing all future commands (until re-enabled).

This is most commonly combined into an `@echo off` as the very first thing in your script.